# Canvas Drawing Over HTML and Preserving Aspect on Screen Resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

**Background**

This is a pretty hard problem that I have been struggling with for a few days now. I am trying to display lessons in a slide-show format. So a lesson is made up of different slides. Now overlayed on top of each slide is a canvas element which is fit to the size of the screen.

```
canvas.width  = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
```

This allows the teacher to draw notes and highlight parts of the lesson on the canvas.

**Problem**

The content of the slide is made up of HTML it looks like this when the slide is loaded.

[image]

When I resize the page however...

[image]

So the problem here is that the canvas 'image' is resized according to the aspect ratio of the page with CSS.

```
#theCanvas {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

But the actual HTML stays the same size, but re-arranges its line-wrap points, bad.

**What I have Tried**

First, I am making all my HTML elements resize according to the width and height of the window using CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 5.9vw;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 3.0vh;
}

h4 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #444444;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 2vmin;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
    font-size: 2vmin;
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

Next I am saving and resizing the canvas image using:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {

    var data = canvas.toDataURL();

    // resize the canvas
    canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    //alert($(container).width());

    // scale and redraw the canvas content
    var img=new Image();

    img.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    img.height = document.body.clientHeight;

    img.onload=function(){
        context.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);
    }
    img.src=data;

};
```

The result in full screen (1920px width)

[image]

When a click the resize window button (1200px)

[image]

That's pretty close.

**Problem**

Now when I drag the corner of the window to resize this happens:

[image]

**Question**

1 - Why is the window.onresize function not triggering when I manually resize the corner of the window?

*(bonus question) Am I going about this the right way, or is it going to be more trouble then its worth to overlay canvas on HTML elements for interactive lessons?*

Comment: is there a live demo somewhere?

Comment: here is a fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/gox4ajty/

Comment: well, it's triggering properly, the issue (i think) lies in the fact that drawing is done in pixel values for x and y position but you want it to depend on percentages. I do not have a solution :/

Comment: If it's possible, it seems like the best solution would be to simply set a fixed size for the slides (the same size as the canvas), and not resize the slide content with the window.

Comment: Thanks anyway Serg, gonna bounty this one when I can.

Comment: @shipshape, will try, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There is no simple solution. The Html is using a sophisticated layout engine. Look at the first 2 images, The first image the time icon is to the left of the text, the next image it is over. In the first image the text is 2 1/2 lines, in the second the text is 4 lines. There is a way by using (abstract markers) on the html, and using them to distort the html image to fit. But there are so many edge cases that using the overlay will become unfriendly and unused.

Comment: ditto @Blindman67's comment. In your case, I would either reset the canvas drawings entirely on resize (just notify you users about it, and during their presentation, they'll have to try not to resize the window), or fix your layout once something has been drawn on the canvas. In current flow, it is impossible to tell if the user wanted to underline some of the text or just make a line that has nothing to do with the text, so you can't know where it should be drawn after resizing.

Comment: I appreciate that this is a tough problem probably with no ideal solution. I am surprised that there are no go-to solutions for collaborating over an html document... if I look at how microsoft edge implements it they stop all responsiveness as soon as you put down a stroke... I appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I mis-understood your problem.

If you want the hand drawn stuff to match the html elements then you need to make sure the HTML elements never change layout and always keep the same relative sizes. In your example that's already **NOT** the case. You've got that "25m" in the top left and "Welcome" in the middle and as you drag the page taller those 2 elements are separating by an amount not proportional to the other sizes of elements so you're already asking for something that's basically impossible.

You could maybe use SVG for all your text, that way it can be scaled to arbitrary sizes where as normal HTML text can't. In other words if you make the page really tall and thin with SVG you'll get tall and thin text and all the positions and sizes will be proportional to their original positions and size where as with HTML the text will not stretch, you set the size to various settings of `vh` but that just means the browser is going to pick the size, not non-proportionally scale the text.

Example: Original desired display

[image]

Change the window to tall and thin (`font-size: 10vh;`)

[image]

Notice the font is not stretched and so the relative sizes and distance between the "25m" and the "welcome" no longer match

Do the same with SVG with `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

[image]

Notice now the both the "25m" and "Welcome" are also tall and thin. This means if you had drawn a box around both in your canvas both boxes would still match after scaling. Without that something is not going to match.

Here's the HTML version of the above

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="time">25m</div>
<div class="center">
  <div>Welcome</div>
</div>
```

And the SVG version

```css
body { margin: 0; }
#foo {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg 
     id="foo" 
     width="100%" 
     height="100%" 
     viewBox="0 0 640 480" 
     version="1.1" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     preserveAspectRatio="none" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     xml:space="preserve" 
     style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">
    <text x="187px" y="240px" style="font-family:'ArialMT', 'Arial', sans-serif;font-size:64px;">W<tspan x="246px 282px " y="240px 240.084px ">el</tspan>come</text>
    <text x="19px" y="35px" style="font-family:'ArialMT', 'Arial', sans-serif;font-size:16px;">25m</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Very interesting! I am going to fiddle around with this concept over the next few days... thanks for thinking outside the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can do your canvas responsive without any resize events. When you need to draw something on canvas, you need to convert a point from window coordinates to canvas coordinates.

```
#theCanvas {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

or

```
#theCanvas {
   max-height: 100%;
   width: auto;
}
```

===========================================================================

```
 var actualCanvasSize = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 var initialCanvasSize = {width:canvas.width, height:canvas.height};
```

What do you think about that?

But if you want to do it with resizing event. There is one lib for detecting HTML elements resize. This lib using some css3 tips and tricks. And works perfectly, and it is more useful and can solve your problem with window resize.But you need to put your canvas in a div and then attach resize listener to a div.
[github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize](https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize)